# replacing an email address using regex.replace

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Basically i need to find an email address from a file and replace the email address with email tags for eg ,

```
`Joeri.DeVos@imec.be`
```

The above address should be replaced with below line

`<email>Joeri.DeVos@imec.be</email>`

I have tried this,

```
Dim strFile As String = File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml")
        strFile = Regex.Replace(strFile, "\<[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z]?\>", "<email>\<[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z]?\></email>")
    File.WriteAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml", strFile)
```

But i am unable to make changes in the file and also the regular expression matches the email address in notepad++

Anyone with the required logic will be really helpful,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example appears to be expecting emails as tags, e.g.

```
stuff<email@domain.tld>stuff
```

to

```
stuff<email><email@domain.tld></email>stuff
```

The docs for "regex.replace" show this format:

```
Dim strFile As String = File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml")
Dim rex as new regex("([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z]?)")
    strFile = rex.Replace(strFile, "<email>$0</email>")
File.WriteAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml", strFile)
```

You could probably do an if/else regex like so:

```
Dim strFile As String = File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml")
Dim rex as new regex("([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z]?)")
Dim rex2 as new regex("(anotherRexEx expression here)")

If rex.IsMatch(strFile) Then
  strFile = rex.Replace(strFile, "<email>$0</email>")
ElseIf rex2.IsMatch(strFile) Then
  strFile = rex2.Replace(strFile, "<tag>$0</tag>")
ElseIf etc... Then
  strFile = etc...
Else
   etc...
End If
File.WriteAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml", strFile)
```

Comment: @jigar No problem!  Which one worked for you?  I don't actually have .NET to test it...

Comment: but instead of $1 i have used $0

Comment: What do you mean by of/else?  What functionality would you like?

Comment: mean if want to use if else condition in my above program where i can use two expression together i.e `if expr1 then something happens elseif expr2 something else happens` is it possible to do so

Comment: You can use the regex IsMatch function to see if there would be a replacement, eg If re.IsMatch(strFile) then strFile = rex.Replace(strFile, "<email>$0</email>") else ...some other regex code here...

Comment: this seems to work good but now one more problem has arised that using the expression i am able to change the required placements but it is also changing the words that are inside the double quotes for example `"<email expression>"` is being replaced with `"<email><email expression></email>" but it should only replace the email expression outside the quotes.

Comment: Then your original RegEx was almost correct with those `<>` tags which should have been reversed `><`:  `new regex("\>([A-Z...a-z]?)\<")` ... `rex.Replace(strFile, "><email>$0</email><")` .  Or maybe try `new regex("[^""]([A-Z...a-z]?)[^""]")`